# How can I crawl an HTML5 website and convert its HTML content to PDF (using a Python or Ruby library)?

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, html, frameworks

I'm looking for an engine/solution/framework/gem/egg/lib/whatever for either Ruby or Python to log into a website, crawl HTML5 content (mainly charts on a canvas), and be able to convert it into a PDF file (or image).

I'm able to write crawling scripts in mechanize so I can log onto the website and crawl the data, but mechanize does not understand complex JavaScript + HTML5.

So basically I'm looking for an HTML5/JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: You *might* be able to do this with a headless browser.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking about but i want it to be scriptable via Python or Ruby - any ideas ?

Comment: See: [Rendering](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#Rendering) I suppose you'd need to look for one that interacts with Python or Ruby?

Comment: I just saw this : https://github.com/assaf/zombie - looks quite promising

Comment: Looks like Capybara is a Ruby project, and both Zombie.js and PhantomJS support that project in some fashion.

Comment: Yo will probably be able to achieve this with [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit) `kit = PDFKit.new('http://google.com')`.

Comment: You can try phantom.js since it can interpret javascript directly with out including other module, and it also has a built-in method to transfer the html files to pdf files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit confusing... sorry re-read my answer after reading the question again.

Your question has two parts:

**1. How can I crawl a website**

Crawling can be done using Mechinize, but as you said, it doesn't do Javascript very well. So one alternative is to use Capybara-webkit or Selenium (firefox / chrome).

Usually this is used for testing, but you may be able to drive it using Ruby code to navigate the various pages.

**2. How can I convert the output to PDF**

If you need to convert the crawled content to PDF, I don't think there is a way to do that. You may be able to take a screenshot (useful for testing) using Capybara-webkit or Selenium, but converting that to PDF may be just a matter of pumping it through some command line utility.

If you're looking for a true HTML to PDF converter (usually used to generate reports from views in a rails app), then use [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit)

Basically it's a WebKit browser that can output to PDF. Really simple to run with.

Comment: actually zombie.js with python did the trick - thank you for this answer

Comment: I won't be able to do it because it's licensed by my company :( sorry.